# What will happen if a server decides to point its A record to localhost?

Tags: domain-name-system

Context:

The Computer Science Department at Purdue University chose to place the following type A resource record entry in its domain name server:

```
localhost.cs.purdue.edu 127.0.0.1
```

Explain what will happen if a remote site tries to ping a machine with domain name `localhost.cs.purdue.edu`.

Is putting a DNS record in a server same as putting an entry in `/etc/hosts` file?

Is this scenario reproducible in a home PC?

Comment: Smells like homework.

Comment: been 3 years since my graduation, trying to learn networking again. But, You can consider it as homework as I'm doing it from home.

Comment: What happens if anyone pings 127.0.0.1?

Comment: You get whatever is hosted on localhost on their own server.

Comment: `You can consider it as homework as I'm doing it from home.` then why aren't you doing it? It shouldn't take more than a few minutes to create a test DNS record on your test DNS server. Initiative counts 20%.

Comment: Guides to do it? Like what keywords should I search for?

Comment: @barnyard9 add a dns record. Set up an training environment.

Comment: The question is good for IT professionals to brush up. I bet if asked in interviews 90% of new graduates wouldn't answer this correctly if they didn't solved this problem earlier.

Comment: @barnyard9 We don't do learning materials. We don't do homelabs. And this question is honestly *trivial* if you understand DNS' role.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What is it that makes [`localhost` and 127.0.0.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) so mystical for many people?

> Explain what will happen if a remote site tries to ping a machine with domain name localhost.cs.purdue.edu.

The same as to what happens when you do that for any host: your resolver attempts to resolve the hostname to an IP-address and when that succeeds the `ping` command will send an ICMP  ECHO_REQUEST datagram  to that IP.

It's that simple.

Then, unless the host where the `ping` command runs is terribly broken the 127.0.0.1 IP-address will be assigned to the loopback interface of that same host so the ICMP  ECHO_REQUEST datagram won't have to leave the host. And then, when the host is not configured to ignore ICMP echo requests, an ICMP ECHO_RESPONSE is elicited.

Note that [RFC 1537](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1537#section-10) states:

> Note that all domains that contain hosts should have a "localhost" A
> record in them.

so fact that the Computer Science Department at Purdue University also chose to place the `localhost.cs.purdue.edu IN A 127.0.0.1` resource record entry in its domain name server is completely normal.